# How to avoid nested flatMap on conditional inside reactive?

Tags: java, spring, reactive, reactor, flatmap

I have a program that will only update if inserted data is different than the old one.

My solution needs a nested `flatMap`, because after save I need to create a log record.
here is my code:

```
public Mono<RescheduleConfiguration> findByIdAndUpdateStatus(MandatoryRequest mandatoryRequest, String id, RescheduleConfigStatus updatedStatus) {
    return rescheduleConfigurationRepository
        .findById(id)
        .switchIfEmpty(
            Mono.error(
                new BusinessLogicException(
                    ResponseCode.DATA_NOT_EXIST.getCode(),
                    ResponseCode.DATA_NOT_EXIST.getMessage()
                )
            )
        )
        .flatMap(rescheduleConfiguration -> {
          if(updatedStatus.equals(rescheduleConfiguration.getStatus())){
            return Mono.just(rescheduleConfiguration);
          }
          return rescheduleConfigurationLogService
              .createRescheduleConfigurationLog(mandatoryRequest, rescheduleConfiguration)
              .flatMap(newRescheduleConfiguration -> {
                newRescheduleConfiguration.setStatus(updatedStatus);
                return rescheduleConfigurationRepository.save(newRescheduleConfiguration);
              });
        });
  }
```

Comment: Shouldn't you return the result of the `rescheduleConfigurationLogService...` call?

Comment: sorry i forget to add return after edit

Comment: Can't doOnNext log the record after save ?